# Simplest way to get 5 most recent tweets from twitter for ASP.Net Webforms

Tags: asp.net, twitter, oauth, webforms

With atom feeds gone I need a quick and simple solution to show my most recent tweets on my site. Widgets are not an option since I need to be able to customize the way the tweets are displayed on the site.

At the very least I'm looking for a basic OAuth sample code. I'm the type of learner who does best at just jumping in with a simple example and tearing it apart until I learn it rather than building it step by step through a tutorial as tutorials often times over complicate something that should only take a few lines of code.

Know of any quick solutions? The newer API seems like a lot of work for such a simple feature. While I'm sure it's worth it, and it's something I'm planning to take the time to learn, at this time I just need to get tweets back up on the site.

Answer (score 0):

My library, [LINQ to Twitter](https://linqtotwitter.codeplex.com/), has built in OAuth support. For ASP.NET examples, you can download the source code and find folders with both WebForms and MVC examples.